# Is it possible or no to use github private repository for web asset and serve via jsdelivr?

Tags: git, github, jsdelivr

I used github-free account and already know how to access my web asset on github repo-public via jsdelivr, then i want make it private. when i set the repo to private it not work, the assets cannot be accessed "failed to fetch"

My idea is :

- Create private repo for web assets.
- create branch that containing: branch/css, branch/js, branch/webfonts. As an example.
- Serve it to jsdelivr cdn for my web.

Is anyone know how to implement github private repo to jsdelivr for web assets?

Answer (score 0):

If you cannot serve directly a private GitHub repository, you might have to setup a plugin like [`private-github-website`](https://www.jsdelivr.com/package/npm/private-github-website)

> Given a github repository and a set of allowed email addresses, serves up the content of the repo to everyone who logs in with an allowed email address.

See its repository: [`TehShrike/private-github-website/`](https://github.com/TehShrike/private-github-website/)

Comment: So, that i have to do are: copy index+server.js to server, modified/fill some parameters in server.js to my values, and load to in html? Then how about to serve on jsdelivr cdn, is it same as regular just use "gh/user/repo"? thanks.

Comment: @Alfan The idea is for that CDN to connect to your private repository, to fetch and serve those files. But I am a bit fuzzy on the setup of such a CDN.